# OpenVPN on Mac OS X. utun or tap/tun.kext

Tags: macos, vpn, openvpn

I am using Mac OS X 10.11.6 and I have found out that I can run OpenVPN client without kextload of tun/tap driver. I suppose Mac OS X has default utun driver.

I just want to clarify when I must load tap/tun.kext and when default utun is enough?

Comment: I noticed the same and are interested by the answer. On linux systems it seems tun are not required.

Answer (score 0):

The tap/tun.kext is needed when you want to use the TAP interface, providing an ethernet bridged network. Or when using older macOS versions that don't provide the utun interfaces.

Otherwise, the utun interface provided by macOS is sufficient and you don't need the kext driver.